# Should posts with more than 10 upvotes be removed from the review queue?

Tags: discussion, review

As I have noticed while reviewing posts in Ask Ubuntu, there are quite a significant number of posts that have at least 10 upvotes but still reside in the review queue.

I think once a post gains a considerable amount of votes, we should have that post be removed from the review. The high number of votes should be considered a strong enough indicator of the quality of the post. It is more than likely that it has been vetted by community users and might have already been reviewed.

Having these posts in the review adds up more chores for the occasional reviewer as well as distract him from attending to posts that require his attention more than the post with such high votes.

If there is any significant reason to have these posts in the review queue, I am more than glad to be made aware of.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is sometimes people will vote on answers that are funny, but are not necessarily useful. A *net score* of 10, though, should certainly be considered sufficient to get a post out of the review queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My intention with review was both to reward great new content, and correct "not-so-great" new content.

By stripping out highly voted content we would be making a judgment call that that 10 votes is quite enough for that post, move along.

Now, keep in mind that as reputation of the posters increases, the posts get automatically removed from review for some of the sort orders.

Additionally, as soon as 2 reviewers review a post it vanishes anyway, so I see very little reason to amend this to the arbitrary 10 vote mark, or 20, or whatever.

Comment: The intention was to mainly focus on content that really needs fixing. That was assuming higher score post are already good enough. But, I have seen circumstances wherein these posts need fixing too. So, I currently don't have problem with the current setup. Thanks for your reply.